# Listbox weird display when update from array by List method in VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code which updates a listbox with list of function and / or sub names.

```
Private Sub lstListOfModNamesInSelWB_Change()
Dim SelItemsCnt As Integer, SelModName As String
If ThisWorkbook.NoEvents Then Exit Sub
SelModName = ""
With lstListOfModNamesInSelWB
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            SelItemsCnt = SelItemsCnt + 1
            SelModName = .List(i, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End With

HideOrShowSubOrFuncItemsAndResizeFrm SelItemsCnt = 1, SelModName
End Sub
Private Sub HideOrShowSubOrFuncItemsAndResizeFrm(vShow As Boolean, Optional ModName As String)
OriLstWidth = lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.Width
lblSearchSubOrFuncName.Visible = vShow
lblSubOrFunc.Visible = vShow
lblSubOrFuncName.Visible = vShow
txtSearchSubOrFuncName.Visible = vShow
lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.Clear
lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.Visible = vShow
If vShow Then
    lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.List = AddRemoveLineNumsErrHndlrsMod.ListOfSubOrFuncNames(cmbWbName.Text, ModName)
End If
lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.Width = OriLstWidth 'it is because somehow after this update this listbox gets weird display
End Sub


Function ListOfSubOrFuncNames(FileName As String, ModuleName)
If Not IsWorkbookOpen(FileName) Then
    ListOfSubOrFuncNames = Array("File Not open")(Array(""))
    Exit Function
End If
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lineN As Long, ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar

Dim startOfProceedure As Long, lengthOfProceedure As Long
Dim CodeModuleObj As CodeModule
Dim ReplaceJump, LineValue, PrevLineValue, LenLine, YesNo

On Error Resume Next
Set CodeModuleObj = Workbooks(FileName).VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule
If CodeModuleObj Is Nothing Then
  ListOfSubOrFuncNames = Array("Module Name " & ModuleName & " not exist")(Array(""))
  Exit Function
End If
Dim ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic As New Scripting.Dictionary
With CodeModuleObj
    ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic.RemoveAll
    For i = 1 To .CountOfLines
        ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic(.ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc)) = Array("")
    Next i
    If ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic.Count Then
        ReDim ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar(1 To ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic.Count)
        ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar(1) = "No Functions Found"
        i = 0
        For Each k In ListOfSubOrFuncNamesDic.Keys
            If k <> "" Then
                i = i + 1
                ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar(i) = k
            End If
        Next k
    Else
        ReDim ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar(1 To 1)
        ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar(1) = "No Functions Found"
    End If
End With
ListOfSubOrFuncNames = ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar
End Function
```

When the UserForm loads:

[image: When the UserForm loads]

After I select a Module Name in first list box:

[image: After I select a Module Name in first list box]

**When I check in debug mode, the display is fine until it reaches `lstListOfSubOrFuncNamesInSelMod.List =...' part of code. But I get *Can't perform operation since the project is protected.* error in immediate window**

Why the listbox got a weird display?

Comment: I'd guess the VBProject is protected and so can't be read?

Comment: After I checked it seems it becomes protected when I loop through the lines of modules.

Comment: You should cancel that `On Error Resume Next` as soon as it's no longer needed.  Then you might see a problem with `ListOfSubOrFuncNames = Array("Module Name " & ModuleName & " not exist")(Array(""))`

Comment: Canceled that `On Error Resume Next`. Found out it is because I set the listbox column count as 3. But did redim `ListOfSubOrFuncNamesVar` as (1 to n) instead of (1 to n, 1 to 3).
Now the weird display gone.